# IIS 7.x, adding an HTTPS-enabled site: SiteCollection.Add(string, string, string, byte[]) overload

Tags: c#, iis, c#-4.0, iis-7, .net-4.0

I need to programatically add an IIS 7.x site and I got stuck when this should be created with a HTTPS/SSL binding by default, usig [SiteCollection.Add(string, string, string, byte[]) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb357409%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Giving <strike>`https:*:80:test.localhost`</strike> `https:*:443:test.localhost` as *bindingInformation* throws an ArgumentException with this message: *The specified HTTPS binding is invalid.*

What's wrong in this binding information?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: *I'm using Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly.*

Comment: Wrong port (443)? Missing certificate?

Comment: @ZombieHunter There's no missing certificate, I'm correctly loading it, I've the byte array. Port... Mmmm, good point hahaha

Comment: @ZombieHunter No luck, it's not the port.

Comment: Just a guess: your certificate is issued for "test.localhost"?

Comment: @ZombieHunter It's for localhost "as is"

Comment: @ZombieHunter Correction, I didn't notice you that it's a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what I did to create https site and it worked. I skip some parts of code here, of course.

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration
...
using(var manager = new ServerManager())
{
    // variables are set in advance...
    var site = manager.Sites.Add(siteName, siteFolder, siteConfig.Port);

    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.AuthRoot, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    // certHash is my certificate's hash, byte[]
    var binding = site.Bindings.Add("*:443:", certHash, store.Name);
    binding.Protocol = "https";

    store.Close();

    site.ApplicationDefaults.EnabledProtocols = "http,https";

    manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

UPD: the certificate is created from a pfx file the following way:

```
// get certificate from the file
string pfx = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.pfx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfx, certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
certHash = certificate.GetCertHash();
```

Comment: It seems to be the way to go, but when I commit changes, it throws an UnauthorizedAccessException and there's no description. Have you faced this problem too?

Comment: You need to have administrative permissions to administer iis and work with auth root certificate store.

Comment: It's not a great silver bullet, but you gave me a good hint, and now it works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you getting the value for certHash?

Comment: You can add site using port 443, BUT you have to clear bindings before adding the final HTTPS binding:
   site.Bindings.Clear();

Comment: Jason Jackson: I updated the answer with certificate creation code.

Comment: If another subdomain in the same site is already using the same (*.yourdomain.com) certificate, you can borrow the certHash and storeName from that. You don't have to load the certificate from a file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see [`BindingInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.binding.bindinginformation%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is without the protocol:

> The value of this property is a colon-delimited string that includes
>   the IP address, port, and host name of the binding.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.binding.bindinginformation%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

There is also a overload of that takes a parameter BindingProtocol:

```
public Site Add(
    string name,
    string bindingProtocol,
    string bindingInformation,
    string physicalPath
)
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359364%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Maybe you should use the Binding object offered by the Site instance as is offers more settings than the SiteCollection instance.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. By the way, I gave a link to the overload doc in MSDN, and if you check **remarks**, you'll find this overload supports protocol in binding information. In second place, I tried to do the other way like your suggestion with same effect.