# C# create site in IIS programatically in asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am trying to create a site in IIS using Microsoft.Web.Administration dll in C#. I am using following code

```
using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            ApplicationPool pool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(ClientDomain);
            pool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
            Site site = serverManager.Sites.Add(SiteName, httpProtocol, httpBindingInformation, physicalPath);
            site.Bindings.Add(httpsBindingInformation, httpsProtocol);
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
```

I am getting  following exception "The method or operation is not implemented" when I run the code from asp.net project but if same code is run from console project, it works fine. Here is the details of the exception

```
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostProperty.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetPropertyValue(IAppHostProperty property)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_CertificateHash()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(String bindingInformation, String bindingProtocol)
   at TestProject.BLL.CRMSiteManagement.CRMSiteIISSetup.Process() in e:\CRMSiteManagement\CRMSiteIISSetup.cs:line 35
   at TestProject.BLL.CRMSiteManagement.CRMSiteService.CreateNewCRMSite(CRMSite newSite) in e:CRMSiteManagement\CRMSiteService.cs:line
```

Seems like an issue with rights but I have not idea how to fix it.
Update 1:
Error is coming on following line of code  on localhost

```
site.Bindings.Add(httpsBindingInformation, httpsProtocol);
```

Comment: Check this other question, it's not exactly the same but there's a sample code of how to create a site... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128732/iis-7-x-adding-an-https-enabled-site-sitecollection-addstring-string-string

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to set the same bindings twice :

1. Once by calling the Add method

`Site site = serverManager.Sites.Add(SiteName, httpProtocol, httpBindingInformation, physicalPath);`

2. Then you add again the same binding:

`site.Bindings.Add(httpsBindingInformation, httpsProtocol);`